# Does com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer have scalability issues (for production environments)?

Tags: rest, tomcat, jersey, jetty, jax-rs

I want to use an embedded http server in my enterprise apps (and move away from standalone containers) and was expecting Tomcat to provide an implementation. I was assuming Sun, Jetty and Jersey's implementations cannot support enterprise load.

But looking at Tomcat, I see no way to run REST apps that use JAX-RS, only servlets. So my questions are:

- Will use of `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` work in a production environment, or do I need another library?
- Am I understanding correctly the boundary between JAX-RS embedded servers and servlet containers (maybe that will explain why Tomcat doesn't provide such a server)

---

Other notes:

- I do not want to use Spring unless that's the only choice

Comment: `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` is deprecated and only good for low load systems that use HTTP/1.0.   Jetty (and Tomcat) can handle huge amounts of load, you'll hit network limits before you'll break a sweat on those Server containers.

Comment: Thanks. Please post as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: Nah, the question feels "off" for the type of question that fits on stackoverflow.  (Asking for product/lib selection advice).

Comment: Modesty :D Where is there a note that it's deprecated? I don't see it in the Java 9 javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html